# text overlapping with chart pandas plot

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to plot a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
dict_object = {'Feats':['AAA_set_a_type_4', 'BBBB_set_B_type_5', 'CCCCC_set_c_Type_6'], 'importance':[3,4,5] } 
df = pd.DataFrame(dict_object )
ax = df .plot( kind="barh")
ax.invert_yaxis()
for i, x in enumerate(df.Feats):
    ax.text(0, i + .5, x, ha='left', fontsize='large')
```

The text however overlaps the bars.
How can I fix that?

Also how can I sort eh bars in descending order?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can just change the bottom positioning a little, from `i + .5` to `i + .4`, set `fontsize` to `medium`, and finally sort `df` with `ascending=False`.

([Documentation](http://matplotlib.org/users/text_props.html) of all text properties)

Here's the updated code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
dict_object = {'Feats':['AAA_set_a_type_4', 'BBBB_set_B_type_5', 'CCCCC_set_c_Type_6'], 'importance':[3,4,5] } 
df = pd.DataFrame(dict_object ).sort(ascending=False)
ax = df .plot( kind="barh")
ax.invert_yaxis()
for i, x in enumerate(df.Feats):
    ax.text(0, i + .4, x, ha='left', fontsize='medium')
plt.show()
```

This is what it looks like:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Not sure how the labels are overlapping.I get this plot:
[image]

If you want to sort just use the sort_values(by) function:

```
dict_object = {'Feats':['AAA_set_a_type_4', 'BBBB_set_B_type_5', 'CCCCC_set_c_Type_6'], 'importance':[3,4,5] } 
df = pd.DataFrame(dict_object )
ax = df .plot( kind="barh")
ax.invert_yaxis()

df.sort_values("importance")

for i, x in enumerate(df.Feats):
    ax.text(0, i + .5, x, ha='left', fontsize='large')
```